# center span in textbox

Tags: html, css

i have a textbox and i want to insert span inside it . and i want to it is center in vertical all the time but my problem is it isn't center in some devices i tested it it with percent values but it doesn't work.

```css
clearBtn {
 position: relative;
 left: 74px;
 transition: left 0.3s;
 font-size: 20px !important;
 font-family: "B Nazanin" !important;
 top:50%
}
```

```html
 <span id="clearBtn1" class="clearBtn">09</span>
 <input type="tel" id="PhoneField" class="phoneBox" maxlength="9"/>

    .
```

Comment: There is no textbox here - are you talking about the input element? Why do you want the span inside the input?

Comment: To accurately center an item within another, it needs to be within the item - this can't be done with an input. You would need to put a div around both and then centre the span to the div, however you may not be able to click on the input under it if the span is on top.

Comment: It would make sense if you choose to use `placeholder` instead

Comment: @kabanus i want to have 09 fix in there and i want to do it with span

Comment: You should consider using bootstrap. With bootstrap, you can do something like this. `<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">09</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>`

Comment: @sepehr Do you mean 09 to be written in the input when it's empty, or always written at the end?

Comment: @kabanus it is always fixed

Comment: Then I think Ferhad answered. Please comment on his answer if it's not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which may help you:

> Try to change the width of div to see, it is always centerd.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width:200px
}
.phoneBox{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.clearBtn {
  position: absolute;
  left:calc(50% - 8px);
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-family: "B Nazanin" !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="clearBtn1" class="clearBtn">09</span>
  <input type="tel" id="PhoneField" class="phoneBox" maxlength="9" />
</div>
```